# Download Messages from Office 365 using IMAP and oAuth2

Tags: azure-ad-msal, mailkit

I need to retrieve email from an Office 365 server using IMAP. The emails will have attachments that need to be processed in C#, then published to another 3rd party.

Initially, we need to connect, but I'm getting an Exception. Here is my current code:

```
        var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions {
            ClientId = "12345...",
            TenantId = "67890...",
            RedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"
        };

        var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .CreateWithApplicationOptions (options)
            .Build ();

        var scopes = new string[] {
            "email",
            "offline_access",
            "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All", // Only needed for IMAP
            //"https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All",  // Only needed for POP
            //"https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send", // Only needed for SMTP
        };

        var authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive (scopes).ExecuteAsync ();

        var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (authToken.Account.Username, authToken.AccessToken);

        using (var client = new ImapClient (new ProtocolLogger("imap.log"))) {
            await client.ConnectAsync ("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            await client.AuthenticateAsync (oauth2);
            await client.DisconnectAsync (true);
        }
```

I don't have Administrator access to the server or user account. I've been provided with a Tenant Id, Client Id, Secret Value, and Secret Id.

When run, the above code throws an Exception on `publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive` ...

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: 'Only loopback redirect
> uri is supported, but urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob was found. Configure
> http://localhost or http://localhost:port both during app registration
> and when you create the PublicClientApplication object. See
> https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details'

I have read the referred URL, but it's still not clear to me why this is happening. Can anyone help me understand what is needed to be done to correct this?

Comment: The problem appears to be with this line: `RedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"`